# how can i set css style to individual dialog button in jquery?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

i try to set css style to individual button jquery,

i try to display dialog box in my webpage, i am using jquery 1.9 ui.

i try do set css style to the button but i cannot find the way, please  help me,

[Fiddle dialog](http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/930/)

this error only show in my jsp not an above fiddle

[image: this error only show in my jsp not an bellow fiddle]

**jquery code:**

```
$('#success').dialog({
    //autoOpen: true,
    height: 180,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    buttons: {
        "Add": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");

            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `ui-button` is the class for the button, is this what you are asking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override default style for button JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201305/how-to-override-default-style-for-button-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the `ui-button-text` class. Like so:

```
.ui-button-text {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: hai josh, it work but style is set title bar close button also , how can i fix it .

Comment: Do you mean that you're only trying to style the first button, but .ui-button-text is styling both? If so you can do something like this: `.ui-button-text:first-of-type { ... }`

Comment: josh, any other way for adding the style to individual button

Comment: The only other way would be to add a class to that button itself, but because this is generated code I'm not sure you'll be able to do that.